# Authentication dialog triggered by URLExecute in Wolfram player does not allow me to type in username/password

Tags: api, authentication, wolfram-player

I have exploration tool that reaches out to elasticsearch for data from a `Manipulate` call. The idea is to share a notebook with some support folk and they can select customers and some parameters and get graphs and tables back and make decisions based on that.

The tool works by making a URLExecute call to an internal elasticsearch cluster. In Mathematica proper it pops up an authentication dialog and remembers username and password for the duration of the session.

When I run this in the player, I get the dialog but it doesn't let me to type anything into the boxes for username/password.

Any idea what gives here? If this is not supported by the player, I wonder why there is a dialog in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in their FAQ: https://www.wolfram.com/cdf/faq/

**Why can't I edit text in CDF Player?**
CDF Player is intended as a deployment option. If you want to edit or create applications or documents, then you need Mathematica or any other CDF content creator, such as Wolfram|Alpha.

Comment: Or Player Pro or you buy Mathematica Enterprise which lets you generated so-called "signed CDFs" which behave similar to Wolfram Player Pro, but run on the free player.
It is not without surprises, but for your use-case it should just work fine.